# No interesting research topics available - should I quit and pay back my stipend?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, quitting

I’m currently enrolled in Mechanical Engineering MSc program in the UAE. I’m on a scholarship program as a TA/RA. I just finished my first semester through which I suffered greatly but I ended up with a GPA of 3.75.

To find a research topic, we are required to choose 3 topics off a list and then be assigned one of them. All three of my choices were given to more suitable candidates. I will have to choose another topic. The problem is all the other topics are of absolutely no interest to me.

I don’t want to waste my time for two years doing something that I hate. I would rather quit now and start looking for a job instead of wasting my time. But if I quit, I will have to pay back the fees and probably my stipend, which could add up to 35,000 USD. This amount increases with every semester I spend in grad school, so I have to decide now whether to stay or leave.

I might be able to pay the 35,000 with the help of my family. But I would like to know if quitting could affect my job prospects and opportunities. What would you do if you were in my place?

Comment: This sounds like an abusive system. Why should you owe anything if you fulfilled your duties as an RA/TA?

Answer (score 5):

> Please keep in mind that to quit I would have to pay back the semester’s fees and probably any stipend I have received during the semester which could add up to 35,000 USD...

"Probably" the stipend? The "probably" makes me nervous -- I think you should start by quantifying exactly how much you would be on the hook for. It could be more than that, or maybe you misunderstand and this would be zero.

> what would you do if you were in my place?

Impossible to answer, partially because I do not know what your "Plan B" is. You need to develop two detailed plans -- one for staying and one for leaving. Only then can you make a good decision.

I would also consider whether you have any professors you trust to discuss this with -- they may be able to help you find a third option.

> I would like to...know if quitting could possibly affect my job prospects and opportunities

Of course not having a degree is worse than having a degree. Paying 35K USD and still not having a degree seems awful. Starting something and not being successful also doesn't look great. But again, the question is: what is the alternative? If you can transfer to a better program, or get an awesome job, then perhaps it is worth it. For sure you don't want to acquire more debt and then not finish.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the points raised by cag51, you should take into account the sort of work you would be doing if you quit the MSc program and take a job. Your reason for quitting is that the program would require you to work on topics that are of absolutely no interest to you. Though I don't know about your interests, I'd expect that many jobs also require you to work on topics that are of absolutely no interest to you. Are you reasonably confident that you could get a job in which you work exclusively on interesting topics? If not, then switching from your MSc program to a job may not really improve anything.

Comment: Doing research on a boring topic is often worse than working at a boring job.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning You may well be right, but I suspect that he reverse is also sometimes true. (I can't claim any expertise on that issue, because I've had the good fortune to avoid both types of boring.)